# Problems when configuring Advance IIS logs with Powershell

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis

The objectives of this script:

- Create a new folder for each site
- Create one log per site per day
- A second script to backup/arhive scripts within a certain format
- Stop all normal logging

---

```
# Ensure cmdlets are available
Import-Module WebAdministration

$Websites = (Get-Website).Name 

foreach($site in $websites)

 {

    Stop-Website $site

}


# Disables http logging module

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter system.webServer/httpLogging -PSPath 
machine/webroot/apphost -Name dontlog -Value true


# Disables the default advanced logging config

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "system.webServer/advancedLogging/server
/logDefinitions/logDefinition[@baseFileName='%COMPUTERNAME%-Server']" -name 
enabled -value false


# Enable Advanced Logging

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter system.webServer/advancedLogging/server 
-PSPath machine/webroot/apphost -Name enabled -Value true


# Move to location to store iis logs

cd C:\inetpub\Logs\Advancedlogs


# Create Folders if required

Foreach($site in $websites)
{
    $FoldersPresent = Test-Path "C:\inetpub\logs\AdvancedLogs\$site"
    if($FoldersPresent -eq $true)
        { 
            Write-host "Folder exsists"
        }
        else
        {
            New-Item -ItemType directory $site
        }

}



# Create hash table

$list = @{'Win32Status'='sc-win32-status';'URI-Stem'='cs-uri-stem';
'URI-Querystring'='cs-uri-query';'Time-UTC'='time';'Time-Local'='time-
local';'Take Taken'='TimeTakenMS';'Substatus'='sc-substatus';'Status'='sc-
status';'Site Name'='s-sitename';'Server-IP'='s-ip';'Server Port'='s-port';
'Server Name'='s-computername';'Protocol Version'='cs-version';'Protocol'='c-
protocol';'Method'='cs-method';'Date-UTC'='date';'Date-Local'='date-local';
'ContentPath'='s-contentpath';'Client-IP'='c-ip';'EndRequest-UTC'='EndRequest-
UTC';'Bytes Sent'='sc-bytes';'Bytes Received'='cs-bytes';'BeginRequest-
UTC'='BeginRequest-UTC';'UserName'='cs-username';'User Agent'='cs(User-
Agent)';'Referer'='cs(Referer)';'Proxy'='s-proxy';'Host'='cs(Host)';
'Cookie'='cs(Cookie)'}


# Set the log file fields

foreach($site in $Websites)
{
    $AppName = $site
    $appdrive = "C:\inetpub\logs\AdvancedLogs\$site"
    $LogRotateFreq = "Daily"

    Add-WebConfiguration /system.webServer/advancedLogging/Server
/logDefinitions IIS:\ -Location $AppName -value 
@{baseFileName="%COMPUTERNAME%-$AppName";enabled="true";
logRollOption="Schedule";schedule=$LogRotateFreq;publishLogEvent="false"}
    $list.GetEnumerator() | foreach {
                                        Add-WebConfiguration "/system.webServer/advancedLogging/Server/logDefinitions/logDefinition[@baseFileName=""%COMPUTERNAME%-$AppName""]/selectedFields" IIS:\ -Location $AppName -value @{defaultValue="";required="false";logHeaderName=$_.Name;id=$_.Value;}
                                        Set-WebConfiguration "/system.applicationHost/Sites/Site[@name=""$AppName""]/advancedLogging" -value @{directory="$appdrive"}
                                    }
}


# Start the websites

foreach($site in $websites)
{
    Start-Website $site
}
```

Links used for guidance:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1185802.aspx?No+log+files+created+by+Advanced+Logging
http://forums.iis.net/t/1193633.aspx?Configure+Advanced+Logging+through+powershellhttp://www.antonyfrancis.net/2014/01/automated-installation-and.html

Comment: and you question / problem is?

Comment: My mistake, the above works, to an extent, it creates the file structure and the log definitions however it doesn't show all definitions are ticked within the editor and most importantly it doesn't create a log file